# Brave browser reroutes all localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/blocks

Tags: reactjs, localhost, brave

I was working on a project where I had to use another persons template

I ran reactjs app on localhoost:3000, the root ("/") automatically defaults to "/blocks" now whenever I run an app at "localhoost:3000/" it automatically switches to "localhoost:3000/blocks".

This happens only on brave and not even on private mode. I have already cleared all data on localhost:3000

Any tips